# Capture Linux shell Commands to file

Tags: logs, bashrc, syslog

I'm trying to capture all Linux Shell command to some file. I tried to use the auditd service but it's not giving me the output I want.

I searched a little and found some nice [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/547788/create-logfile-for-all-fired-commands-on-server) .

Step 1:  vi /etc/bashrc and append the following line at the end:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

Step 2:

Set the syslogger to trap local6 to a log file by adding this line in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
local6.*                /var/log/cmdlog.log
```

The output is :

> Jan 10 11:05:20 itdev-server eddiem: root [7310]: vim /etc/rsyslog.conf [0]

**This is a very good solution and fit what I need, but I've some issues I can't fix.**

1) How to ignore the "Enter" button, every time I press the Enter button it logs the last command.

2) When you ssh into another server it doesn’t record the ssh command until you disconnect the session, but more importantly it doesn’t capture the commands that were ran on the remote host.

If anyone have some solution or a workaround it will be great!

**Thanks in advance.**

EddieM

Comment: ick. that's an awful solution. that's a keylogger, and easily circumvented to boot.

Comment: It's a Big Brother solution. Hope that you do not type a password by accident at the command prompt :-)

Comment: If you have any better solution I will glade to hear :)

Comment: audit is what you are looking for, it is configured in /etc/pam.d (I can't write as answer as I don't have access to my test host).

Comment: How can I configure the auditd service to log all Shell commands? I didn't find the answer in the WEB.

Answer (score 2):

The `script` command may be useful for you. It captures *everything* in a session and writes it to a file (`typescript` by default).

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ date
10 Jan 2016 12:45:59
$ id
uid=1000(roaima) gid=50(staff)...
$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript


$ sed 's/^/|   /' typescript    # cat typescript, with "|" on front of each line
|   Script started on 10 Jan 2016 12:45:56
|   $ date
|   10 Jan 2016 12:45:59
|   $ id
|   uid=1000(roaima) gid=50(staff)...
|   $ exit
|   exit
|
|   Script done on 10 Jan 2016 12:46:03
```